# Como usar e-mails no Azure?

Tags: envio-de-email, smtp, microsoft-azure

Coloquei um dos meus sites no Azure.

Não há serviço de e-mail?

Lá consegui disparar e-mails de servidores externos, mas quero criar e usar um no mesmo domínio que está no Azure.

Como resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 3):

Edson, ainda não há serviço de e-mail disponível no Windows Azure. Porém você pode usar empresas parceiras ou serviços especializados. Dentre os melhores hoje estão:

- **[Send Grid](http://sendgrid.com/)** - Nunca usei, porém é bem recomendado. E oferece serviço
  gratuito até 25 mil envios.
- **[Mail Gun](http://www.mailgun.com/)** - Já usei, acho fenomenal, praticamente tem tudo para envio e recebimento de e-mails. Grátis até 10 mil envios

Existe também a possibilidade de executar o seu servidor de SMTP e fazer a integração utilizando Service Bus (mais comum) ou Windows Azure Virtual Network.

Comment: Mas no caso essas empresas fazem o disparo ou vão prover as contas de email? Eu quero criar contas no meu @dominio.com. O disparo em si é não é o problema a partir do momento que eu dispor do servidor. Seria uma alternativa eu ter uma VM com um mail server. Uma VM small custa menos de $15 mas eu precisaria configurar tudo e mais um pouco.

Comment: Sim, você pode usar o seu domínio. Fora que além de não se preocupar com configuração eles vem com vários serviços já prontos. O mail gun por exemplo já vem com sistema pronto onde você é notificado sobre as reclamações sobre envio de spam, gerenciamento de bounce e logs!

Comment: Vou checar. Parece bom. Obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Optei por usar o Zoho Mail. Rápido, eficiente e gratuito. Recomendo. https://www.zoho.com/mail/

Answer (score 2):

Edison, tudo bem?

Você pode utilizar também o Office 365 no plano mais básico conta com email, calendario e outra pancada de recursos, por um preço justo, pode ser um diferencial bem bacana para os seus clientes.

Se você ainda quiser integrar seus atuais sites com o Azure AD, pode utilizar SSO, com login único para os seus sites e Email.

Da uma olhada, mesmo que for só por curiosidade =)

http://products.office.com/pt-BR/business/office-365-business-essentials

Answer (score 1):

Como serviço em um modelo PaaS ou SaaS o Azure não possui, porém como foi mencionado acima a oferta para serviços de e-mail seria o Exchange Online através do O365 e que que possui uma imensa integração com o Azure.

Porém se mesmo assim você pretende ter um serviço do Azure utilizando os recursos de IaaS, você pode fazê-lo.

Recentemente tive duas experiências, uma delas foi um cliente trabalhando com uma solução Open Source de e-mail utilizando as VMs com distribuições Linux e a outra que iniciei recentemente é um processo de migração de Exchange on-premise de um cliente e iniciamos o trabalho com base nas diretrizes desta documentação https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj619301(v=exchg.150).aspx onde a Microsoft trata dos pré-requisitos para se virtualizar ambientes com Exchange.

Neste caso dentre os pré-requisitos vale ressaltar o seguinte ao utilizar o Azure:

*> Deployment on Microsoft Azure virtual machines is supported if all storage volumes used for Exchange databases and database transaction logs (including transport databases) are configured for Azure Premium Storage.*

Lembrando que o serviço de Storage Premium até a presente data (22/06/2015) ainda não está liberado no Brasil, porém hoje já não existe blockers ao querer montar tal ambiente no Azure.